# How to disable parameter in lspkind?

Tags: neovim, cmp

I want to disable the import information in the list. But I can't find any information on how to do this anywhere.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZCYx.png)

I searched a lot, but I didn't find any information.

here is the code of my cmp plugin configuration

```
cmp.setup({
            completion = {
                completeopt = "menu,menuone,preview,noselect",
            },
            snippet = {
                expand = function(args)
                    luasnip.lsp_expand(args.body)
                end,
            },
            mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
                ["<TAB>"] = cmp.mapping.select_next_item(),
                ["<S-TAB>"] = cmp.mapping.select_prev_item(),
                ["<C-n>"] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
                ["<C-e>"] = cmp.mapping.abort(),
                ["<CR>"] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = false }),
            }),
            sources = cmp.config.sources({
                { name = "nvim_lsp" },
                { name = "luasnip" },
                { name = "buffer" },
                { name = "path" },
            }),
            formatting = {
                format = lspkind.cmp_format({
                    mode = "symbol",
                    maxwidth = 50,
                    ellipsis_char = "...",
                }),
            },
            window = {
                completion = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
                documentation = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
            },
        })
```